# is that possible to add mutiple images save in one column in mysql using dajngo framework

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, e-commerce, mysql-python

iam a beginner in the field. i currently doing a ecommerce website which sells samrtphone.

1. I want to add mulitple product images. In order to add the images
   do i need more columns for every image.
2. How to add mutiple ram and price for product. Samrtphone have
   mutiple ram according to
   ram price varies.user can choose ram  of the product. How to add
   this  in to my project using mysql. Do ineed more  columns for
   every ram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your **models.py**
add,

```
...
    images = models.ManyToManyField("Image", blank=True)
    varieties = models.ManyToManyField("Variety", blank=True)
...

class Image(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images/")

class Variety(models.Model):
    ram = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```